# Firebug and AMF post

Tags: coldfusion, firebug, amf, amfphp, flex2

I have to debug a website that uses a swf to send amf posts to a flex2gateway.
In Firefox's "Firebug > Net"  I see the POST url and when I click on it, **the Post tab shows scrambled jiberish**:

[image]

**The response is also scrambled:**

[image]

**But the headers and cookies are not scrambled:**

[image]

[image]

**How can I unscramble the post so that I can create a curl with the proper post values. And how can I unscramble the response?**

Comment: Your screenshots show various AMF related tabs at the right of the *Cookies* tab. What do they show?

Comment: All AMF related tabs on the right show empty.

Answer (score 2):

AMF is a binary format. As such Firebug and Chrome Dev Tools don't do a very good job of being able to read them. In the past, I have used a product called [ServiceCapture](http://kevinlangdon.com/serviceCapture/) to 'read' AMF messages. [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) is another product that can do this.